# is there a way to load a default image in picasso

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso

i cannot load an image in picasso from my drawable due to resons known only to picasso, so whever picasso fails to load i want to load a default image please help

```
    @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                 final Context context =getApplicationContext();
                 final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
              int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                  R.dimen.padding_medium);
              imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

             PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
             ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
                      imageView.setTag("myview" + position);

            Picasso.with(context).load(mImages[position]).resize(320,280).centerInside().placeholder(placeholderDrawable)
                .into(imageView,new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.c3);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                        });
```

iv included callback in the hope to do something but my brain is not working, any1 help

Answer (score 36):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(www.google.com/image/1).placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_person_image)).error(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_person_image)).into(pictureView);
```

This is what i'm currently using (placeholder URL of course). It will try and load the image you provide in the "load()" part, will show the "placeholder()" part before it has downloaded the image, and if it fails it will show the "error()" part.

Personally i have both the placeholder() and error() part to show the same image, but you can load two different images.

Comment: it loads the default image no doubt but there is still a weird problem in which the 3rd image is not loaded neither the default image n i have a beautiful blank screen. no problem with the 3rd image itself but Picasso hating the no.3 slot.pl.waiting for help

Comment: I am loading over 250 images in a listview with Picasso and that exact line of code i posted, so you should probably check if the image link in 'mImages' array is actually valid.

Comment: this mImages[] has all the drawable like R.drawable.image1 etc etc, all the other images load ok, y should only the 3rd image disappear, its playing peek a boo wit me, sometimes complete blank screen n sometimes it shows for like2 sec before vanishing

Comment: Did you try removing the PicassoTools.clearCache() call? I've never used it, and haven't faced any problems.
Also, did you try to ONLY use the line of code i posted, without adding callback or resize? It could be some of those parameters that are failing

Comment: i was facing out of memory problems so i added that to improve the cache size but lets remove this n let me see if i get the image

Comment: n i added the resize part to your code n checked nothing happened to the almighty elusive 3rd image. i didnt add that callback tho coz i wasnt sure wat to do with it

Comment: FYI both `placeholder()` and `error()` accept a drawable resource ID. You don't have to actually load the `Drawable` yourself.

Comment: @Jake Wharton ye it accepts drawable, so how does it help my case?? the 3rd image keeps disappearing, provide some enlightenment please

Comment: I am loading the images from a web server can I load the placeholder and the error images from the same url too? and for me Picasso.with has also error. thanks